# Local planner's concrete class is defined where in move_base?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to utilize `turtlebot_navigation` and replace local planner with my planner. Can someone tell me where in `turtlebot_navigation` concrete class for local planner is specified?

I understand `move_base` pkg employs "interface programming" based on `pluginlib` to call local planner's functions w/o knowing the name of the local planner (`nav_core`)'s concrete class. To achieve that, some other pkgs (`base_local_planner` etc.) contain the [plugin description file](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pluginlib#The_Plugin_Description_File)s (as blp_plugin.xml), but the pkg I'm about to utilize doesn't seem to have that file. The only possible description that I found in `turtlebot_navigation` about specifying concrete class is in `config/base_local_planner_params.yaml` where there's a `TrajectoryPlannerROS` section.

Is the `yaml` description above the one? Or is it something like, if there's no plugin description file found then default class (I assume `base_local_planner` in this case) gets automatically used? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12373/local-planner%27s-concrete-class-is-defined-where-in-move_base?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot uses the same nav_stack that other ROS robots use. In order to develop your own planner for it, you must make your own plugin for base_local_planner interface type, which is specified in nav_core. `base_local_planner` is `move_base`'s default local planner. In order to change it, you can add the following lines to turtlebot_navigation/config/move_base_turtlebot.launch inside of the `move_base` node:

```
<param name="base_local_planner" value="your_local_planner/YourLocalPlanner" />
```

You build your own plugin package, develop your own blp_plugin.xml, and load it in place of base_local_planner.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-21**:
Thx, now my plugin started working. I also missed exporting (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pluginlib#Exporting_a_Plugin) and combining xml file and exporting steps, now everything makes sense.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-19**:
"your_local_planner" is the namespace that you define for your controller in the plugin.xml, and "YourLocalPlanner" is the type that you give to it. Typically, convention is to use your_class_namespace/YourClassName.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-18**:
Thanks. I assume for local planner that 'name="base_local_planner"' is fixed, and then "your_local_planner" is namespace and "YourLocalPlanner" is class name?